# AngularJS, Mocha, Chai: testing service with promises

Tags: angularjs, testing, mocha.js, karma-runner, chai

I've found several posts that shows this code as a way to do async unit testing:

The service:

```
angular.module('miservices', [])
.service('myAppServices', ['$http', 'httpcalls', function($http, httpcalls) {
    this.getAccountType = function(){
        return httpcalls.doGet('http://localhost:3010/...').then(function(data){
            return data;
        }, function(error){
            ...
        });
    };
    ...
```

The test:

```
describe('testing myAppServices', function(){

beforeEach(module('smsApp'));
it('should handle names correctly', inject(function(myAppServices){
  myAppServices.getAccountType()
  .then(function(data) {
      expect(data).equal({...});
});
...
```

We're using AngularJS, Mocha, Chai and we have Sinon installed.

The test never gets to the `.then` part, but why?

Thanks!

Comment: The issue is not a promise but $http. You have to mock requests and you don't do that.

Comment: Do you mean httpBackend them?

Comment: That's right. If doGet and getAccountType do nothing to actual http response, you can skip this spec and mock getAccountType for other specs.

Comment: Thanks @estus! One last question: what if we do need to test a real response from the backend?

Comment: Save it for e2e, that's what is to be tested there.

Comment: Thanks @estus! I bet there is need for a good tutorial about it out there...

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing your service I would recommend to mock your "httpcalls" service (as that is outside scope in this test).

To mock it you can have several ways, one approach would be to have a mocks module that you use only with your unit tests.

```
 angular.module('miservices.mocks', [])
.service('httpcalls', ['$q', function($q) {
    this.returnGet = '';
    this.doGet = function(url) {
           return $q.when(this.returnGet);
        };
    };
```

And your unit test then would be something like:

```
describe('testing myAppServices', function(){

beforeEach(function() {
module('smsApp');
module('miservices.mocks');
});
it('should handle names correctly', inject(function(myAppServices, httpcalls){
  httpcalls.returnGet = 'return data';
  myAppServices.getAccountType()
  .then(function(data) {
      expect(data).equal('return data');
});
...
```

Because we are inserting the mocks module after application module, httpcalls service gets overwritten by its mock version and allows us to test properly myAppServices without further dependencies.

Comment: Thanks @pedromarce, I'll give it a try